# How to read a single nested property from YAML using Java SnakeYaml?

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I'm a bit confused, how do I quickly retrieve a property from a loaded `Yaml` SnakeYAML object? I shouldn't have to traverse through maps etc., right?

e.g.

```
app:
   ftp:
     host: 1.1.1.1
```

I read in my file

```
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application-test.yaml");
    Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
```

and now I should be able to quickly do something like

`obj.get("app").get("ftp").get("host")`
or
`yaml.get("app.ftp.host")`

right? But there are errors: Something has to be cast to a Linked Hash Map, or there has to be iteration of fields, etc. I don't want to iterate anything myself, I want to quickly get a nested property with some kind of getter.

Why do I have to do this craziness to get a nested property even with the SnakeYaml library added to the project?

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application-test.yaml");
Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

LinkedHashMap objLevel1 = (LinkedHashMap)obj.get("app");
LinkedHashMap objLevel2 = (LinkedHashMap)objLevel1.get("sftp");
Integer port = (Integer)objLevel2.get("port");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the layout of the data in your file with classes:

```java
class Ftp {
    public String host;
    public int port;
}

class App {
    public Ftp ftp;
}

class Data {
    public App app;
}
```

Then you can do

```java
Data data = yaml.loadAs(inputStream, Data.class);
String host = data.app.ftp.host;
int port = data.app.ftp.port;
```

If you don't want to do that, you can always write a getter yourself:

```java
<T> T getFromYaml(InputStream input, String[] path, Class<T> type) {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    Object data = yaml.load(inputStream);
    for (String item: path) {
        Map map = (Map) data;
        data = map.get(item);
    }
    return (T) data;
}

// and then in your loading code:
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application-test.yaml")) {
    Integer port = getFromYaml(inputStream, new String[] {"app", "ftp", "port"}, Integer.class);
    // do something with it
}
```

The first method is preferred since SnakeYAML can yield good error messages, for example if the `port` value is not an integer or `ftp` is not a mapping. The second method will leave you alone with a casting exception (you can of course expand it to output good error messages).

Comment: I shouldn't have to write a getter myself. That' what the library is for.

Comment: There is no standard for a „YAML path“ (as there is for JSON), hence the library doesn't implement an API for it. Your suggestion of chaining `get` calls obviously can't work because at any level the value could be a string that doesn't have `get()`, or a list that would have `get()` but with an index. Welcome to statically typed country.

Comment: Then how does Spring Boot automatically process YAML? In Spring Boot you can say "LEVEL1_LEVEL2_LEVEL3" (like SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE) and it'll automatically pull "Level1: Level2: Level3". The same facility should be available in the library.

Comment: Spring Boot is build upon Java Properties. When you feed YAML into it, it transforms the YAML to Properties by joining nested level keys with `.`, hence `level1.level2` works. Spring Boot *uses* SnakeYAML as backend, and therefore is on a higher level. It doesn't make sense to say „the lower level library should implement the functionality of a higher level library“.